# Angular+REST как правильно организовать взаимосвязь

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Делаю учебное (для себя) задание с целью изучить, закрепить материал.
Используется Angular+REST

Главная страница обращается к серверу и получает массив данных (для наглядности $scope.messages), например сообщения. Angular их выводим в таблицу, в таблице есть ссылка Edit, при нажатии вылезает окно с данными этого сообщения.

index.html

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-area col-lg-8" id="inputName" ng-model="current.author">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-4 text-area-margin">Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control text-area col-lg-7" rows="3" ng-model="current.message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-area-margin">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default text-area-button" ng-click="closeEditFrame()">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default text-area-button" ng-click="saveEditedMessage(current)">Save</button>
        </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

script.js

```
    $scope.editMessage = function (data) {
        $scope.current = data;
        $scope.showEditFrame = true;
    }

    $scope.saveEditedMessage = function (data) {
        $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url:  $scope.url + 'message/' + data.id,
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).success(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.showEditFrame = false;
        }, function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

Я упускаю функцию получения всех данных, тут это не важно.

Так все работает, но возникает такой момент, если я поменяю данные на стороне клиента и не сохраню их, а нажму отмена, они сохранятся в скоупе и буду отображаться как измененные, то же произойдет если по какой то причине они не сохранятся на сервере.
Очевидно, что ng-model тут не подходит, что подходит? И как правильно организовать эту взаимосвязь клиента и сервера?
Примерно тот же вопрос у меня к дате изменения сообщения, ее должен генерировать сервер или клиент?

Answer (score 0):

Правильный ответ

```
    $scope.editMessage = function (data) {
        $scope.current = angular.copy(data);
        $scope.showEditFrame = true;
    }
```

И дальше работаем с копией.

Comment: Не сказал бы, что это лучший вариант, но вполне подходит.

Comment: Другого я пока не нашел, а чего то лучшего ни кто не подсказывает.

Comment: Сделать директиву, которая будет требовать ngModel на всю сущность, копировать её, а при сохранении переприсваивать.

Comment: Я пока не дошел до директив в процессе, но если есть примеры, буду рад.